# Resolve an ownership issue in Rust

Tags: rust, ownership

I am facing an ownership issue on line number 28. it says borrowed value document does not live long enough.

```
pub fn start<'a>(url: String) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let resp = reqwest::blocking::get(url).unwrap();
    let mut buf = "".to_string();
    if resp.headers()["content-encoding"] == "gzip" {
        let bytes = resp.bytes().unwrap();
        let mut decoder = GzDecoder::new(&bytes[..]);
        decoder.read_to_string(&mut buf).unwrap();
    } else {
        println!("bad content-encoding");
    }
    let anchors: Vec<&str> = vec![];
    let result: Vec<&str> = fetch_links(&buf, anchors);
    return result;
}

fn fetch_links<'a>(buf: &str, mut anchors: Vec<&'a str>) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let document = Html::parse_document(&buf);
    let anchor = Selector::parse("a").unwrap();
    let elements = document.select(&anchor);
    for element in elements {
        match element.value().attr("href") {
            Some(result) => {
                anchors.push(result);
            }
            None => {}
        }
    }
    return anchors;
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document lives in the scope of function `fetch_links`, therefore it also owns `elements`.

When you push `element` into `anchors`, the `&str`s will be freed after the scope ends, and the values are dropped. Hence document does not live long enough.

I don't think it is possible to use `Vec<&str>` as `anchors` in this scenario, try using a `Vec<String>` with `.clone()`.